NO sound "Dummy Output" Redmi-Book-Pro-16-2024 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
after the installation sound system is not working and check the settings it shows only "Dummy Output".HERE THE INFO
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 1
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: igen6_edac
    Kernel modules: igen6_edac

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P [Intel Arc Graphics] (rev 08) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P [Intel Arc Graphics]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 197, IOMMU group 0
    Memory at 4818000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915, xe

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 7d03 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 2
    Memory at 4819280000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal_pci
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci

00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e4d (rev 20) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122, IOMMU group 3
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: 86000000-860fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 10) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123, IOMMU group 4
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=2b, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 3000-3fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: 80000000-85ffffff [size=96M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 4010000000-480fffffff [size=32G] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 7e4c (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 5
    Memory at 48192d2000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 7d0d (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 6
    Memory at 4819240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_vsec
    Kernel modules: intel_vsec

00:0b.0 Processing accelerators: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake NPU (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 175, IOMMU group 7
    Memory at 4810000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at 48192d1000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_vpu
    Kernel modules: intel_vpu

00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 151, IOMMU group 8
    Memory at 48192b0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 10) (prog-if 40 [USB4 Host Interface])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 8
    Memory at 4819200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at 48192d0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 7e45 (rev 20) (prog-if 00 [8250])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125, IOMMU group 9
    Memory at 48192a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
    Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 141, IOMMU group 10
    Memory at 86100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7e7f (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 10
    Memory at 48192c8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 48192cf000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18, IOMMU group 11
    Memory at 48192c4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32, IOMMU group 12
    Memory at 48192ce000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7e70 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 149, IOMMU group 13
    Memory at 48192cd000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e02 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 2309
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 14

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 198, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 48192c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 4819000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_mtl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P SMBus Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 48192cc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P SPI Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Meteor Lake-P SPI Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 7e800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
    Kernel modules: spi_intel_pci

01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Shenzhen Longsys Electronics Co., Ltd. FORESEE XP2000, Lexar NM760 NVME SSD (DRAM-less) (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Shenzhen Longsys Electronics Co., Ltd. Lexar NM760 NVME SSD (DRAM-less)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at 86000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme


This question is similar to: Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This helped me

Check ALSA Settings: Open a terminal and run alsamixer to check if the sound levels are correctly set. Make sure none of the channels are muted.

Verify Kernel Modules: Ensure all necessary sound modules are loaded. You can do this by running sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel and sudo modprobe snd-sof-pci-intel-mtl.

Update System Packages: Update all system packages to the latest versions using sudo pacman -Syu.

Configure GRUB: Edit the GRUB configuration file to disable dmic_detect for snd_hda_intel.
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Change the line in /etc/default/grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"

Then update the GRUB configuration with
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Enable and Start Services: Enable and start the necessary services with
systemctl --user enable wireplumber
systemctl --user start wireplumber

Reboot: Reboot your system to apply all changes.


